# Tkinter Scale widget with non-integer resolution

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a Tk.Scale widget to my application, but I have a problem with setting non-integer value to the resolution parameter. If I pass an *integer* value to Scale constructor, it works correctly, but with any *non-integer* value (say 0.1) my scale widget does not move. It appears at the right place and looks just fine, but doesn't respond to my attempts to move it.

Here is my code related to the creation of scale widget:

```
    self.sliderValue = Tk.DoubleVar()
    self.slider = Tk.Scale(self.frame,
                           from_=float(self.lowerValue.get()),
                           to=float(self.upperValue.get()),
                           orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL,
                           length=180,
                           variable=self.sliderValue,
                           resolution=0.1, # Here is the problem
                           command=self.sliderMoved)
```

The problem is I can not reproduce this issue outside of my application. In other words, if I create just a simple window with one scale widget, it works with any resolution values. So it seems that the problem is hidden somewhere outside of this constructor call, but I can not figure out where. May be someone had the same problem and can advise me what should I check.

Addition:
May be it is important: in standalone (working) case the value above the slider is in "1.0" format (with the dot as the separator), and in my broken application it is "1,0" format (with the comma as the separator). May by some kind of type/format mismatch is happening here.

Addition 2:

Here is minimal example:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from pylab import *

# cla()  # if you uncomment these two lines,
# clf()  # scale will break for non-int resolutions

root = Tk.Tk()

var = Tk.DoubleVar()
scale = Tk.Scale(root, from_=6.0, to=8.5, variable = var,
                resolution=0.1, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL)
scale.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it sounds like there is something that deadlocks your program when the resolution is float, which is really hard to debug without seeing more code, please try to construct a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Start by including the code to `self.sliderMoved` and try adding print statements at various points in it.  If the problem only happens when you try to move the slider the problem might be there.

Comment: `'1,0'` doesn't represent a number.

Comment: Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, the problem is still there even if I do not pass self.sliderMoved method at all.

Comment: TigerhawkT3, I know, but I do not understand why it becomes like that. Trying to create MCVE now.

Comment: Ok, while trying to create a MCVE I found the place, that cause all troubles. In a separate function, that is being called _way_ before the creation of the troubled Scale, I create a plot using matplotlib. In this function I clear the plot with clf() and cla() functions. If I comment out these calls, the slider (which does not exist at the moment) works fine. I can not understand why it is going like that. I'm happy, that I located the problem, but I do not have any ideas what is wrong. May be some global variables in these mpl functions overwrite some Tk variables, I dont know.

Comment: MCVE is added to original post. clf() and cla() functions beak the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems that this problem does not appears anymore (Python 2.7.11+).